# How to fix this `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found` error?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, autocompletion, filetype, syntax

I am trying to set up syntax keyword based omnicompletion in vim.

I have defined a few `syntax keyword Constant`s in `~/.config/nvim/syntax/spl.vim`
They are correctly detected and highlighted.
They are also showing up in `:syntax list` as below:

```
:syntax list                                                                                                 
--- Syntax items ---
Operator       xxx match #[=+\-*\/%]#
String         xxx match /".*"/
Comment        xxx match +\/\/.*+
Constant       xxx SWAP_OUT FREE_PAGE_TABLE INT_CLOSE DISK_SIZE GET_CODE_PAGE IDLE_PROCESS INT_LOGOUT
                   CONTEXT_SWITCH MAX_FILE_SIZE INT_DELETE WAIT_TERMINAL INIT_PROCESS MAX_BUFFER
                   RESOURCE_TABLE_OFFSET PAGE_SIZE INODE_TABLE WAIT_DISK FILE 
                   .. truncated ..
```

`:set omnifunc` outputs `omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete`

But still Ctrl+X Ctrl+O shows `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`

How to fix this?

Vim version is: `NVIM v0.4.2`

```
set ft?
  filetype=spl
scriptnames
  ...
  ftdetect/spl.vim
  syntax/spl.vim
  ...
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Interesting first question; I hope you get an answer! You might want to verify `:set filetype?` and `:scriptnames` give what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble :)
`:set filetype?` gives `filetype=spl` and `:scriptnames` contains `ftdetect/spl.vim` and `syntax/spl.vim`, which are expected values.